# split javascript string to get desired values 

Tags: javascript, string, split

I want to extract the date and the username from string using `.split()` in this particular string:

```
var str ='<a href="/user/xxspmxx/profile">XxSPMxX</a> on 08/30/2012';
```

I want `XxSPMxX` in one variable and `08/30/2012` in the other.

Comment: It wasn't before Zoltan edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just `split`:

```
var x = str.split('</a> on ');

var name = x[0].split('>')[1];
var date = x[1];
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/YUaAT/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `split` is the right tool for this job. Try this regex:

```js
var str ='<a href="/user/xxspmxx/profile">XxSPMxX</a> on 08/30/2012',
    name = str.match(/[^><]+(?=<)/)[0],
    date = str.match(/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/)[0];
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ve7Y/

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to match using a regular expression, build up a small array to get the parts of the anchor, and then use substring to grab the date.

```
var str = '<a href="/user/xxspmxx/profile">XxSPMxX</a> on 08/30/2012';
var matches = [];
str.replace(/[^<]*(<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/a>)/g, function () {
    matches.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, 4))
});
var anchorText = matches[0][2];
var theDate = str.substring(str.length - 10, str.length);

console.log(anchorText, theDate);
```

working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dkA6D/